# Active Directory User Sync with Joomla Hitting limit at 1015

Tags: php, joomla, active-directory

I am the systems admin at a small school, and I am attempting to use a CLI PHP script to import all of our AD users into the Joomla! database.  This script comes with JMapMyLDAP (all of the rest works great, by the way).  I was initially hitting a limit of 1000 users, but that was "fixed" by increasing the default AD limit.  Now, however, I am running into errors after processing 1015 users.  I now receive a message stating that there has been a

> Fatal error (Failed to bind with proxy user.) for user: XXXX
>   There are 318 remaining members, and I'm positive it isn't a permissions issue because I can bind to these accounts through the test tools.

I'm including the PHP script so that someone might be able to tell me if there is a way to bypass whatever limit I might be hitting at 1015.  I can't seem to find an indicator of what the actual problem is because the only limit that seems to exist at 1015 is how many groups you can be a part of.  That is not my issue...

If it is possible, it would also work if someone could figure out a way to reverse the array of the script.  As it is right now, 1015 users are presented alphabetically.  The script continues to do as it should for those users, and presents the errors for the remaining 318 after, so my thinking is that, if the array is reversed alphabetically, then the script could basically just start at the bottom of the list and work its way up.  This isn't ideal, but it is also not a script that will have to run more than a handfull of times.

I have attempted several times to sort, narrow the scope of, or otherwise surpass the total number I seem to be capable of using, but I know pretty much nothing about PHP.

Thank you all in advance for your help and your time.

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP Version 5.3
 *
 * @package    Shmanic.CLI
 * @author     Shaun Maunder <shaun@shmanic.com>
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2011-2013 Shaun Maunder. All rights reserved.
 * @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

// Make sure we're being called from the command line, not a web interface
(!array_key_exists('REQUEST_METHOD', $_SERVER)) or die;
define('_JEXEC', 1);

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the J! Framework and CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.php';
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

// Load the configuration if one doesn't exist
(class_exists('JConfig')) or require_once JPATH_CONFIGURATION . '/configuration.php';

// Configure error reporting to maximum for CLI output.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Load Library language
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();

// Try the Shmanic LDAP file in the current language (without allowing the loading of the file in the default language)
$lang->load('files_cli_shmanic_ldap', JPATH_SITE, null, false, false)
// Fallback to the Shmanic LDAP file in the default language
|| $lang->load('files_cli_shmanic_ldap', JPATH_SITE, null, true);

// Get the Shmanic platform and Ldap libraries.
require_once JPATH_PLATFORM . '/shmanic/import.php';
shImport('ldap');
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.
/**
 * This script will fetch all the LDAP users in the specified
 * base DN and synchronise them to the Joomla! database.
 *
 * @package  Shmanic.CLI
 * @since    2.0
 */
class LdapCron extends JApplicationCli
{
    /**
     * Entry point for the script.
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   2.0
     */
    public function doExecute()
    {
        // Setup some stats
        $failed     = 0;
        $success    = 0;
        $errors     = array();

        // It appears we have to tell the system we are running with the site otherwise bad things happen
        JFactory::getApplication('site');

        $this->out(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13001'));
        // Get all the valid configurations
        if (!$configs = SHLdapHelper::getConfig())
        {
            // Failed to find any Ldap configs
            $this->out(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13003'));
            $this->close(1);
        }

        // Check if only a single config was found
        if ($configs instanceof JRegistry)
        {
            /*
             * To make things easier, we pretend we returned multiple Ldap configs
             * by casting the single entry into an array.
             */
            $configs = array($configs);
        }

        $count = count($configs);
        $this->out(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13002', $count))->out();

        // Loop around each LDAP configuration
        foreach ($configs as $config)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get a new Ldap object
                $ldap = new SHLdap($config);

                // Bind with the proxy user
                if (!$ldap->authenticate(SHLdap::AUTH_PROXY))
                {
                    // Something is wrong with this LDAP configuration - cannot bind to proxy user
                    $errors[] = new Exception(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13011', $ldap->info), 13011);
                    unset($ldap);

                    continue;
                }

                // Get all the Ldap users in the directory
                if (!$result = $ldap->search(null, $ldap->allUserFilter, array('dn', $ldap->keyUid)))
                {
                    // Failed to search for all users in the directory
                    $errors[] = new Exception(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13012', $ldap->getErrorMsg()), 13012);
                    unset($ldap);

                    continue;
                }

                // Loop around each Ldap user
                for ($i = 0; $i < $result->countEntries(); ++$i)
                {
                    // Get the Ldap username (case insensitive)
                    if (!$username = strtolower($result->getValue($i, $ldap->keyUid, 0)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        // Check if this user is in the blacklist
                        if ($blacklist = (array) json_decode(SHFactory::getConfig()->get('user.blacklist')))
                        {
                            if (in_array($username, $blacklist))
                            {
                                throw new RuntimeException(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13025'), 13025);
                            }
                        }

                        // Create the new user adapter
                        $adapter = new SHUserAdaptersLdap(array('username' => $username), $config);

                        // Get the Ldap DN
                        if (!$dn = $adapter->getId(false))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        $this->out(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13020', $username));

                        // Get the Ldap user attributes
                        $source = $adapter->getAttributes();

                        // Get the core mandatory J! user fields
                        $username = $adapter->getUid();
                        $fullname = $adapter->getFullname();
                        $email = $adapter->getEmail();

                        if (empty($fullname))
                        {
                            // Full name doesnt exist; use the username instead
                            $fullname = $username;
                        }

                        if (empty($email))
                        {
                            // Email doesnt exist; cannot proceed
                            throw new Exception(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13022'), 13022);
                        }

                        // Create the user array to enable creating a JUser object
                        $user = array(
                            'fullname' => $fullname,
                            'username' => $username,
                            'password_clear' => null,
                            'email' => $email
                        );

                        // Create a JUser object from the Ldap user
                        $options = array('adapter' => &$adapter);
                        $instance = SHUserHelper::getUser($user, $options);

                        if ($instance === false)
                        {
                            // Failed to get the user either due to save error or autoregister
                            throw new Exception(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13024'), 13024);
                        }

                        // Fire the Ldap specific on Sync feature
                        $sync = SHLdapHelper::triggerEvent('onLdapSync', array(&$instance, $options));

                        // Check if the synchronise was successfully and report
                        if ($sync !== false)
                        {
                            // Even if the sync does not need a save, do it anyway as Cron efficiency doesnt matter too much
                            SHUserHelper::save($instance);

                            // Above should throw an exception on error so therefore we can report success
                            $this->out(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13029', $username));
                            ++$success;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13026'), 13026);
                        }

                        unset($adapter);
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e)
                    {
                        unset($adapter);
                        ++$failed;
                        $errors[] = new Exception(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13028', $username, $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                $errors[] = new Exception(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_ERR_13004'), 13004);
            }
        }

        // Print out some results and stats
        $this->out()->out()->out(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13032'))->out();

        $this->out(JText::_('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13038'));

        foreach ($errors as $error)
        {
            if ($error instanceof Exception)
            {
                $this->out(' ' . $error->getCode() . ': ' . $error->getMessage());
            }
            else
            {
                $this->out(' ' . (string) $error);
            }
        }

        $this->out()->out(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13034', $success));
        $this->out(JText::sprintf('CLI_SHMANIC_LDAP_INFO_13036', $failed));
        $this->out()->out('============================');
    }
}

JApplicationCli::getInstance('LdapCron')->execute();
```

Comment: And you are absolutely positive that there is not a problem with either 1014 or 1015 such as that they violate a Joomla rule on username or email?  Joomla has some rules for validating them.

Comment: Thanks for the response...  I'm positive that these don't have issues, and the code is pretty smart.  When it runs into a problem with one of the users, it just skips it, and then it moves to the next one.  I thought that it might have something to do with an allowed number of errors for every x amount of processed users, but I've repaired the 3 that were encountered, and it still stops at 1015.

Comment: I really can't think of a reason why it would die at that point.  Have you tried asking Shaun?  (Also i'm assuming you are not setting any of these to be superadmins, because they require special handling).

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help.  I'm stuck also..  I was going to ask, but Shaun's site very clearly states he will not provide support.  And no, they aren't supers.  However, again, this script seems to pull them and import them correctly anyway.  The supers were imported early in the script process because they all happen to start with a "C."  Any chance you might just know how to flip the sort to where it pulls starting with Z instead of A?